# jQuery set attribute onclick all elements instead of using inline JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some inline JS that I'm having trouble changing over to jQuery. I would like to remove all the inline onclick events and target them all by class.

HTML - checkbox

```
 <td class="center">
    <?php if ($product['selected']) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>_select" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" checked="checked" />
    <?php } else { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" id="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>_select" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" />
    <?php } ?>
  </td>
```

HTML - inline JS

```
<input type="text" class="editable" name="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>_model" id="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>_model" value="<?php echo $product['model']; ?>" size="16" onclick='document.getElementById("<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>_select").setAttribute("checked","checked");' />
```

The above code works but when I try to use jQuery`version 1.7.1` it breaks. Here is the code I have tried.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".editable").live("click", function() {
     $("#<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>_select").attr("checked", "checked");
     $("#<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>_select").checked = true;
   });
});
```

I'm not really familiar with jQuery but I think it's close. Any Ideas?

EDIT:
The problem is with the `$("#<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>_select")` it works if hard coded. KevinB was correct even though ive never had this problem before but never used it within here `$(element)`

Comment: you don't want to use php in that click event. Also, you should probably upgrade from .live to either .on or .delegate, .live gets removed in newer versions.

Comment: Why are you changing it to jQuery if you are unfamiliar with jQuery?

Comment: @Mathletics because I wanted to remove all the inline JS. There are many of them and it's something I would be able to re-use. Maybe I'll just leave it, didn't think I would have so much trouble with this simple event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.live` was [deprecated in version 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/live/) -- probably explains it.  Use `.on` instead.

```
$(".editable").on("click", function() {
   var name = '<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>';
   console.log("Name: " + name);
   var el = $("#" + name + "_select");
   console.log(el);
   el.prop("checked", "checked");
});
```

Comment: Why use `.on(element, event` etc vs `$(element).click(function () {` Just user preference?

Comment: OK, i have tried all of those and none of them work. `$(element).click(function () {` `.on`

Comment: @Mark no -- if you use the first version, then the events get delegated (ie, a listener is not added to every match).  It just depends on the best fit for each scenario.

Comment: Should this code work? Because it doesn't. If it looks ok to you guys then ill assume it's something else. I have always embedded php within the JS without problems.

Comment: `prop()` doesn't work either, I think its a problem with targeting the elements.

Comment: @handmdmr I think it must be.  I'd try outputting to console to see what the selector is.

Comment: @Mark: `$(element).click(handler)` is [now a shortcut for `$(element).on('click', handler)`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), so it makes no real difference any more.

Comment: @McGarmine Thanks, that's what i needed, It didn't like the php within the selector `$(element)`

Comment: @DavidThomas So the concept of event delegation isn't a factor anymore?

Comment: @DavidThomas No, it was a selector issue, I totally missed that it had to be within the loop so I just wrote a function and called it onclick inline on each element within the loop. then I can reuse it throughout the project.